# How to find a row or column under specific conditions in a matrix in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, find, row

For example, if we have a matrix or say array with the following format

How can we find the index of rows or columns which only have numbers between 10 to 20 inside ?

```
M = array(c(1,1,12,34,0,19,15,1,0,17,12,0,21,1,11,1), dim=c(4,4))
```

And, also, I am not allowed to use for or while loops to do this. 
Another thing is that the matrix or array may have a more than 2 dimensions. if the method can also apply to multi-dimensional matrix or array, it will be better for me.  Thanks.

Instead of trying to find the index of qualified single elements, I need to find those rows or columns in which all the elements are between the interval.

In this example, I hope to have a result telling me that Row number 3 is a row that all the numbers within this row are between 10 to 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)`.  Here I assume *between* means 10 and 20 are non-inclusive

```
which(M > 10 & M < 20, arr.ind = TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   3   1
# [2,]   2   2
# [3,]   3   2
# [4,]   2   3
# [5,]   3   3
# [6,]   3   4
```

This will also work on 3-dimensional arrays (and higher).

```
## Three dimensions
dim(M) <- c(2, 4, 2)
which(M > 10 & M < 20, arr.ind = TRUE)
#      dim1 dim2 dim3
# [1,]    1    2    1
# [2,]    2    3    1
# [3,]    1    4    1
# [4,]    2    1    2
# [5,]    1    2    2
# [6,]    1    4    2

## Four dimensions
dim(M) <- rep(2, 4)
which(M > 10 & M < 20, arr.ind = TRUE)
#      dim1 dim2 dim3 dim4
# [1,]    1    2    1    1
# [2,]    2    1    2    1
# [3,]    1    2    2    1
# [4,]    2    1    1    2
# [5,]    1    2    1    2
# [6,]    1    2    2    2

## ... and so on
```

**Note:** To include 10 and 20, just use `M >= 10 & M <= 20`

**Data:**

```
M <- structure(c(1, 1, 12, 34, 0, 19, 15, 1, 0, 17, 12, 0, 21, 1, 
11, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

**Update:**  From your edit, you can find the row numbers for which all values are between 10 and 20 with

```
which(rowSums(M >= 10 & M <= 20) == ncol(M))
# [1] 3
```

Comment: thank you, it is really helpful. but I am also struggling in how to find the rows or columns in which all the numbers are qualified. even under a three dimensional situation.

Comment: I mean your method shows clearly the index of each "qualified cells". It is really helpful, but finally I need to find out the rows or columns in which all the numbers inside are all between the interval...

Comment: edited. thank you so much....

Comment: thank you! I will try this out, and will try to apply it to more complicated 3 dimensional cases! thank you again

Comment: For higher dimension arrays, you may try something like `apply(M, 4, function(x) which(rowSums(x >= 10 & x <= 20) == ncol(M)))` for (example) 4-dimensions

Comment: Yes, you are really good at it.